# Same controller, two different models

Tags: angularjs

This looks like a simple problem but I cannot figure out the best way to approach it:

The big picture: I want to have a reusable address template and include it (using grunt-includes) inside other templates when an address block is needed. For the address template to be stand-alone and reusable, I have attached an address controller to it and its internal model is called addressModel.

The problem: I have a single page that includes that reusable AngularJS *address* template TWICE: one address is going to be used for Billing and the other one for Shipping.

Question: how do I customize each block to handle their own corresponding model on the parent controller's scope? In other words, from the parent controller I want to say that the model for the first address block is `$scope.billingAddress` and the model for the second one is linked to `$scope.shippingAddress`, knowing that inside each address controller I only have access to their local `$scope.addressModel`, and I have no way to know from any of the child controllers which `addressModel` was intended for the current controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this purpose you should use directive with isolated scope.
Example:

```
angular.module('some-module', []).directive('address', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            address: '=data'
        },
        template: '<ul><li>{{ address.city }}</li><li>{{ address.street }}</li></ul>' //or you can use 'templateUrl'
    };
});
```

Simple usage:
Insert in your template: `<address data="billing.address"></address>`

Extended example you can see here: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vicune/1/edit?html,js,output)

More about directives: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Hopefully it will help you.